# SMB JCIFS file writing issue

Tags: java, file-io, smb

I want to write a password protected file at remote location in JAVA. So I am using SMB api(JCIFS).
However I am seeing an inconsistency in the data written at destination file.

E.g.
If my intension is to write the data as,

```
AB
CD
EF
GH
```

When I write the data in file,
The api misses some characters,
Some times it writes,

```
AB
CDE //EF not on next line & 'E' missed by api.
GH
```

some times it writes,

```
AB
CD
EFH
```

---

I am using `SMBFileOutputStream` to write a line by line in file.

```
smbOutputStream.write(myString.getByte);
```

Comment: Post some example code.

Comment: SmbFile file = new SmbFile("networkPath");
SmbFileOutputStream sbmFileOutputStream = new SmbFileOutputStream(file, true);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for(Student stud : listOfStudent){
sb.append("\n");
sb.append(stud.getName()+"|");
.....
}

sbmFileOutputStream.write(sb.toString.getBytes);
sbmFileOutputStream.flush();

catch()
catch()
......
finally{
sbmfileOutputStram.close();
}